# Extra pixel in firefox on dropdown hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using `top: 100%` to push the sub-menu dropdown below the main navigation bar on hover but in Firefox the menu is pushed below the border of the menu causing a 1px gap. In webkit browsers it works the way I'm wanting it to, where it shows the sub-menu with no gap in between. I'm using 100% to avoid hard coding in a value.

I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/FernE97/pen/lnyzJ) for testing. I set the border around the menu to red to make it easier to see the issue. The second nav is just showing the hover state.

**update**

Without `display: table;` on the `.nav-main` element, the 1px gap goes away, but I'm using it so I can add `display: table-cell;` to the nav list items to spread them out and fill the entire nav. Any ideas on how to get around that?

**html**

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav-main">
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link Two</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**scss**

```
$pink: #ed2490;

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-main {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid lighten(black, 22%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: lighten(black, 8%);
    @include background(linear-gradient(bottom, lighten(black, 8%), lighten(black, 36%)));
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;

    > li {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;

        &:hover {
            .sub-menu {
                top: 100%;
            }

            a {
                background: lighten(black, 18%);
                background: rgba(black, 0.25);
            }
        }
    }

    a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 10px;

        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            background: lighten(black, 18%);
            background: rgba(black, 0.25);
        }
    }

    .sub-menu { // dropdown
        position: absolute;
        top: -999px;
        z-index: 10;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 200px;
        background: lighten(black, 4%);

        li {
            border-top: 1px solid lighten(black, 18%);

            &:first-child {
                border-top: 0;
            }
        }

        a:hover {
            background: $pink;
        }
    }
}

// For example only
.styleguide-dropdown {
    padding: 40px 20px 130px;
}

.nav-main {
    border-color: red;

    .psuedo-hover {
        a {
            background: lighten(black, 18%);
            background: rgba(black, 0.25);
        }

        .sub-menu {
            top: 100%;

            .psuedo-hover {
                background: $pink;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A workaround that doesn't solve the actual issue but...  Just add a black border around your navigation in order to "seal" the gap?

Comment: If you hover over slowly though, once you hit the border, the dropdown goes away.

Comment: I don't have the time to really investigate this right now, but I am doing something very similar without SCSS.  Feel free to have a look at the code for the following link to see if you can ascertain any differences that may cause your problem.

http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/

Comment: I figured out that the `display: table;` on the `.nav-main` is what causes it to behave differently. Without that the 1px gap goes away but I need to use it so the links fill the entire space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shudder, anything with display: table-* is inherently going to be very hard to style consistently across browsers.

But, that said, its really not your issue.  The following fixes both work:

```
.submenu { display:none;}
:hover > .submenu { display: block;}
```

or

```
.submenu { height: 0; overflow:hidden }
:hover > .submenu { height: auto; }
```

And either of those should be better for reflow/repaint/re-render than crazy shifts in top.  Also they will be more robust in case you ever wanted to re-use that nav lower on a page, without just "hiding" things by sending them up with a negative top.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, using display none and block fixed the issue.

Comment: yeah, I added the height option in case you were going to later use css transitions or something, that way you could get that fancy "scroll down" effect.  You could also get clever with things like opacity and transitions and get a lovely little fadeIn/fadeOut effect.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the 1px border around `ul` solves the problem; then you can add top and bottom borders to each `li`. Though the `border-radius` won't be calculated the same way.

I believe the reason is that the height of `ul` is more than the height of `li` with this 2px of border and so 100% of the height of `li` isn't enough... but I'm really not sure of this one.

Here's a working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jsBEt

Comment: I tried your demo and I still have the one pixel difference in Firefox.

Comment: I'm still seeing the 1px border too. Nice idea though